# how do i get imageViews to be able to go back and forth between imageviews?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, android-imageview

not sure if i should use switch and case or if statements or what???
    ImageView m1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

```
    m1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {



            if(on=true)
            {
                 v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music2);
                 on=false;
                 }

            if(on=false)
            {
                 v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music);
                 on=true;
            }
```

Comment: You can't switch on a boolean in Java. You might as well use an if statement. Also see the answer below, you don't need check if a boolean is true or false, just use the boolean by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If `on` is a boolean, you can just do that:

```
if(on){
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music2);
}else{
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music);
}
on = !on;
```

**NOTE**: I guess your code is not working now because of this: `if(on=true)`, here you are setting a value on `on`, if you want to compare, you should actually use `==`. In this case, with a boolean, you don't even need to compare.